# How to 7za file without specify archive name

Tags: command-line, compression, 7-zip

Say have an executable target.exe, is there any way to compress this file into target.zip without specify archive name(output name) by using 7zip command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with the command line utility alone. The `a` command expects an archive file name (to add to or create) and a list of files.

If you try without specifying an archive name, you get a `System Error: Incorrect Function` because the first argument expected is an archive name. If you specify an executable for example, it will say archive type not supported, as it will try to make a `.exe` archive.

**However**: 7-zip is open source software. You can modify how the `a` command works to expect different arguments, or even make a new switch of your own!

Here's a Perl script I quickly threw together which should be able to do what you want:

```
#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe

use warnings;
use strict;

exit unless @ARGV;

my $path = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"; # modify this accordingly
my $infile = (split /\./,$ARGV[0])[0];

system("\"$path\" a $infile @ARGV");
```

The script will take the name of the first argument (before the `.` in the file name) and use that as the base for the archive name. I've assumed you're on Windows by the `.exe` reference, change the shebang line if not.

Place the script somewhere in your PATH and use it like so:

```
7z.pl target.exe otherfile someotherfile
```

It will create an archive named `target.7z` with those 3 files enclosed.

Comment: nice interesting solution

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do is a gzip function. 7zip supports gzip as one of it's unzip methods although it doesn't support it a zip function.
See the info here http://www.gzip.org/.