# Looking for archive tool with very simple command line usage

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, zip

OS: Windows XP

Requirements:

1. Support compress/uncompress zip format
2. Like gzip can use the original file name as archive file name, so no need to specify archive file name. `gzip target_folder`, so the output will be `target_folder.zip`.

Comment: Are you looking for more of a command-line tool, or a GUI'd one?

Comment: **gzip -c** writes to stdout leaving original file untouched. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Isxek - command-line tool. thanks.
@Umber Ferrule - I meant 'gzip target_folder' only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[7-zip](http://7-zip.org) has this behavior and can compress/uncompress zip format:

[image]

As you can see the file extension has been stripped, and the rest of the file name used as the archive name.

**Edit:** For a command-line solution, you can still use 7-zip. Check out my script [here](https://superuser.com/questions/115007/how-to-7za-file-without-specify-archive-name/115011#115011). You can modify it like so:

```
#!C:/Perl/bin/perl.exe

use warnings;
use strict;

exit unless @ARGV;

my $path = "C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7z.exe"; # modify this accordingly
my $infile = (split /\./,$ARGV[0])[0];

system("\"$path\" a $infile.zip @ARGV");
```

Just tested it on my fasm folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you could do (if you only want to compress one file or directory tree per archive) is to put one of the following lines into a batch file in your 7-Zip install directory (say `zip.bat`):

For a **Zip** archive: `7z.exe -tzip -r a %~n1.zip %1`
For a **7-Zip** archive: `7z.exe -r a %~n1.7z %1`

And then call with: `zip.bat target_folder`